# How to compile C++ library inside ROS package?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package structured as follows:

```
-include
-src
-my_submodule
  -include
  -src
  CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
package.xml
```

The my_submodule folder is basically a C++ library that I want to compile along with my ROS package and use as a dependency. I could install my_submodule and use find_package(my_submodule), but I want to compile my_submodule along with the package.

What do I need to modify to compile my_submodule along with my package? The idea is that my_submodule is not dependent on ROS or my package, but I want to include without installing separately.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350311/how-to-compile-c++-library-inside-ros-package?/) by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't seem like a ROS question but a CMake question. For example: regardless of ROS, are you aware of how to link up multiple cmakelists together?

A good hint is looking at the `add_subdirectory()` macro in CMake.

Examples:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/master/nav2_system_tests/CMakeLists.txt#L51

https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/eloquent-devel/CMakeLists.txt#L33

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2020-04-22**:
Yes. I use add_subdirectory(), but the subdirectory is not compiling. The command doesn't seem like it is doing anything.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-04-22**:
Without *far* more information, there's no help anyone can give. Please edit your original question with more detail.

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2020-04-23**:
add_subdirectory() did work. I changed the build directory, and I was checking wrong directory to see if worked properly... Thank you for your answer!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-04-23**:
No worries! Can you mark the question as correct so its off the unanswered questions queue?